# how to restrict in datepicker current date to next 15days in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying this code but it is not working.
thanks to all.
I am using uidatepicker with select minimumDate. but require current date with additional 15 days in datepicker swift 2.0.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.minimumDate = datePickerView.date

        //datePickerView.maximumDate = datePickerView.date

 datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BookAppointmentView.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        }

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker)->NSDate {

        let baseDate:NSDate = NSDate()

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


        DatePickerField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
        print("date of bookAppointment\(DatePickerField.text!)")

       return newDate!

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.
dateByAddingTimeInterval is one, in which you add time in seconds:

```
datepickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() // current date
datepickerView.maximumDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(1296000) // date + 15 days
```

You can also do:

```
datepickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() // current date
let maxDateComponent = NSDateComponents()
maxDateComponent.day = //days you want to add
datePickerView.maximumDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(maxDateComponent, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

In which you add the time in days.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this extension method helps

```
extension NSDate {
    func dateByAddingDays(days:Int) -> NSDate? {
        let c:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        c.day = days;
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(c, toDate: self, options: [])
    }
}
```

this code is not tested. but i have used dateByAddingComponents in some cases

Comment: datePickerView.maximumDate = NSDate().dateByAddingDays(15)!